# How can i write the x path for this?

Tags: selenium

I have entered the xpath as "`html/body/div/div/div[2]/ks-swiper-container/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/button`" &  its not working.Please help me to write xpath?

```
<button class="appshortcutWidget md-button md-ink-ripple layout-align-center-center layout-column md-blue-theme" ng-transclude="" type="button" layout-align="center center" layout="column" click-outside="closeAll()" ng-dblclick="doubleClick()" sglclick="singleClick($event)" aria-label="Profile">
```

Comment: Please share your html code...

Comment: in this case i think that the class name of the button could change depends on theme or something else so it's may by dynamic better take upper id of the tree for example //div[@id='something']//button[1]

Answer (score 1):

Try this simple:

```
//button[aria-label='Profile'][type='button']
```

Answer (score 0):

XPath as below:-

```
//button[@class='appshortcutWidget md-button md-ink-ripple layout-align-center-center layout-column md-blue-theme' and @type='button']
```

OR

```
//button[@class='appshortcutWidget md-button md-ink-ripple layout-align-center-center layout-column md-blue-theme']
```

Hope it will help you :)